# Вывести данные в цикле while наоборот

Tags: php, циклы

у меня в цикле есть нумерация строк `$i++`.

Выводятся на экран записи 1 2 3 и тд.

Мне необходимо вывести их наоборот, 3 2 1.

Записей может быть неограниченное количество, они выгружаются из базы. подскажите как сделать

Comment: При выгрузке из базы используйте обратную сортировку, к примеру: "SELECT * FROM `database` ORDER BY `id` DESC;"

Comment: Видимо вам заранее надо узнать количество записей что бы отсчитывать от него. Это можно делать либо отдельным запросом на количетво, либо в том же запросе. Кроме того нумерацию записей можно сделать в самом SQL-запросе (если база у вас SQL конечно). Больше конкретики в вопрос добавьте

Comment: нумерацию в запросе? SQL, да. подскажите, очень интересно. чтобы по убыванию не ограниченно количество. а вообще понял  про первый вариант, у меня цикл с постраничной навигацией. и сначала и так и так идёт запрос на количество записей нужных.

Comment: @intro94 интересно как этот запрос будет работать, если поставить реальное имя базы данных?

Comment: @alias суть была не в названии, а в правой части. Вместо `database` подразумевалось название таблицы. Чисто по-невнимательности написал. Точнее изменил скопипастенное со своего же кода. :) Исправить не смогу - заблокировано изменение. Давно был коммент отправлен.

Comment: @PHPcoder А вы СУБД не указали. На БД поддерживающих оконные функции с помощью row_number(), на mysql сложно, придется либо инициализировать переменную в from подзапросом возвращающим count(), либо считать с 1 при прямой сортировке и потом пересортировывать в обратном порядке во внешнем запросе

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 100; //это колличество ваших записей
while($i > 0) {
   $i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, по типу :

```
$i = 100;
while($i > 0) {
   $i--;
}
```

Хорошо подходит для ситуаций, если Вам действительно необходимо вывести нумерацию строк в обратном порядке. В реальности, я, по правде говоря, слабо себе представляю таблицу, в которой было бы уместно пронумеровать строки в обратном порядке (в случае, если столбец несет смысл именно порядкового номера строки).
Как правило интересует порядок сортировки в зависимости от значения какого-то конкретного параметра, например идентификатора записи. 
Поэтому советую в первую очередь обратить внимание на вариант, предложенный пользователем **@intro94** в комментарии к Вашему вопросу, с сортировкой в запросе:

```
SELECT * FROM t_table ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Плюс подобная конструкция даст Вам возможность менять условия сортировки, например, сортировать сначала по дате подачи заявки, а в какой-то момент изменить правило на сортировки по дате *подтверждения* заявки.

Но опять же, вариант с декрементом подойдет Вам в случае, если действительно нужно просто пронумеровать строки в обратном порядке (хотя единственный сценарий, при котором я вижу хоть какую-то пользу от этих показателей, - пользователь, который заходит на первую страницу, видит общее количество записей в таблице, смотря на номер первой строки; но в таком случае, не лучше ли вынести эту цифру куда нибудь за пределы таблицы, так, чтобы она была доступна для просмотра не только на первой странице, и явно озаглавить ее значение "Всего строк").